# Not able to remove WordPress page title without removing the content aswell

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am making a WordPress theme with the framework from Underscores.me.

I do not wish to show the page title on pages. So I thought I could use some simple CSS to do it:

```
.entry-title {display:none;}
```

But doing this also removes all content on the page basically just showing an empty page.

Then I thought I could remove the title by deleting this in my theme:

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

But by removing the above also removes all content from showing.

Its like the title has to be shown in order to show content. I never had this problem before and I have developed a few themes with Underscores.me. But it is like the new version has to show page titles in order to show the content.

Have anyone any idea what to do?

I am running on a localhost so I cant show my problem but I am using the newest theme from [Underscores](http://underscores.me/).

Even if I install a "disable page title" plugin the plugin also removes the content when disabling the title.

I really hope someone had this problem before! :)

Extra info:

This is how the page.php looks like:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' ); ?>

            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

This is the template it calls for:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'open2day' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

As I said, if I remove the title with CSS it also removes the content.

Comment: The last template, content-page.php, is missing the last </article>, it has been your mistake on copy/paste, or is this really missing in that template?

Comment: Try commenting just the PHP command that has `the_title()`. That is, don't delete the `<header>` tags around it; just comment out the PHP command.

Comment: @ThemesCreater </article> is not missing I just forgot to copy/paste it

Comment: @PaulJ Commenting out the h1 also removes the entire page content :S

Comment: Is `WP_DEBUG` enabled? Any errors in your debug.log file on removing `the_title()`

Answer (score 0):

please use !important in your css like below
hope this will work.

```
.entry-title {display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you comment out the following line:

```
<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

your page no longer has an h1 element of class "entry-title".

Your CSS is expecting this element to be on your page, so unless you want to edit your CSS, you can just add the following empty element:

```
<h1 class="entry-title"></h1>
```

This should solve your problem and allow the content to be displayed whilst hiding the page title.